# ordinary differential equation using octave for tan functions showing errors

Tags: octave, ode

I tried to solve an ordinary differential equation using octave4 .It works fine for sin and cosine functions .But for tan it is showing error as

```
 # Define the right-hand side of the equation:
function ret=f(y,x);ret=tan(x) ;end;
# x will be on the interval [0,1]; y(0)=0.5
# x will be the set of moments of time:
# ywill be the values of the function at these moments of time.
y=lsode ('f', 5, (x=linspace(0,100,100)));
plot(x,y)
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**error**

```
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.6201527144160D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.6201527144160D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.6758957986520D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7056317233321D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7210002414438D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7288235178363D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7327811043353D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7347822361589D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7357991952018D-16
 LSODE--  WARNING..INTERNAL T (=R1) AND H (=R2) ARE
       SUCH THAT IN THE MACHINE, T + H = T ON THE NEXT STEP
       (H = STEP SIZE). SOLVER WILL CONTINUE ANYWAY
      In above,  R1 =  0.1570796326795D+01   R2 =  0.7363225763750D-16
 LSODE--  ABOVE WARNING HAS BEEN ISSUED I1 TIMES.
       IT WILL NOT BE ISSUED AGAIN FOR THIS PROBLEM
      In above message,  I1 =        10
```

Please help me to solve the ordinary differential equation for tan functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem quite simple - **tan** function has a discontinuity at **x=pi/2 + pi*k**. Change definition of x. This code works well:

```
x=linspace(0,pi/2-0.01,100);
y=lsode ('f', 5, x);
plot(x,y);
```